# timeSetEvent missing with VS2017 on ARM platform

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017 for an ARM platform (Raspberry Pi 3 B + with windows iOT). I am looking for using `timeSetEvent` function from `mmiscapi2.h`. Unfortunately this function is not available on ARM platform.

Is there another header which may replace `mmiscapi2.h` and `timeSetEvent`? Or should I use a different function n for ARM?

I'm having many difficulties, and I do not know if I'm clear. If not, ask questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[timeSetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757634(v=vs.85).aspx) is desktop API and it is obsolete. New applications should use CreateTimerQueueTimer to create a timer-queue timer.

And unfortunately, CreateTimerQueueTimer is not supported on Windows 10 IoT Core. [Windows 10 IoT Core only supports a subset of the Win32 and .Net API surface area available on various prior versions of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/iotcoreportingtool).

UWP is main application type on Windows IoT Core. In UWP you can use [ThreadPoolTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer) and [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) to create periodically timer.

You can reference "[HelloBlinkyBackground](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/93c8a2b872083a4b0e968365592a42f26cd966a7/Samples/HelloBlinkyBackground/CPP/StartupTask.cpp#L46)" and "[HelloBlinky](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/55bd183b8fd704b1bce3ffd8f5d6d805b3eec70f/Samples/HelloBlinky/Cpp/MainPage.xaml.cpp#L35)" samples for how to use them.

**Update:** Here is a sample of DispatcherTimer in UWP.

MainPage.xaml.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

using namespace App5;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    timer_ = ref new DispatcherTimer();
    TimeSpan interval;
    interval.Duration = 500 * 1000 * 10;
    timer_->Interval = interval;
    timer_->Tick += ref new EventHandler<Object ^>(this, &MainPage::OnTick);
    timer_->Start();

}

void MainPage::OnTick(Object ^sender, Object ^args)
{

}
```

MainPage.xaml.h

```
//
// MainPage.xaml.h
// Declaration of the MainPage class.
//

#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace App5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainPage sealed
    {
    public:
        MainPage();

    private:
        void OnTick(Platform::Object ^sender, Platform::Object ^args);

        Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer ^timer_;

    };
}
```

C++ UWP project structure：

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the aid. For now, I didn't succeed. I use Visual Studio 2017, and it does not recognise DispatcherTimer(), it may not be in the references, so I'm looking on that side.

Comment: @KingoftheStoneAge `DispatcherTimer()` is included in `Windows::UI::Xaml` namespace you need to reference it. I update my answer by adding a simple sample code you can have a check.

Comment: In fact I'm trying to upgrade an old software, which was running on win32. And make it running on ARM (Raspberry Pi 3 B+).
Especially, right now I'm trying to upgrade a .dll, and the refererences do not want to add

Comment: Since your initial question is developing an app for ARM. For upgrading existing WIN32 app maybe you can try [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root). ["Bringing your existing desktop apps to UWP"](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/17/bringing-your-existing-desktop-apps-to-uwp/#3x3hqXzyC3QVG5Om.97)